# When does Sonar's TryStatementTree#resourceList return a Tree that isn't a VariableTree?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I came across the `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.TryStatementTree` interface while going over some code for a SonarQube plugin. One of the rules implemented goes over the variables defined in a try-with-resources block.

Looking at the `TryStatementTree#resourceList`, I can see that it returns a `ListTree<Tree>`. This can be iterated over in a number of ways. In one case, the plugin inspects the name of the variable declared. When this happens, the `Tree` is cast to `VariableTree` because `Tree` is a more generic interface that doesn't provide access to variable names via `IdentifierTree`.

This is where the cast is in the code I'm looking at, a class that extends `BaseTreeVisitor` and implements `JavaFileScanner`.

```
@Override
public void visitTryStatement(TryStatementTree tree) {
  // ...
  tree.resourceList().stream()
     .filter(resource -> resource instanceof VariableTree) // Is it possible for this condition to evaluate to false? 
     .map(VariableTree.class::cast)
     .map(resource -> resource.simpleName().name())
     .forEach(SomeClass::handleThisCase);
  // ...
}
```

Looking at the [Java Language Standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3), I can't think of a situation when a `try` statement would have something in place of the resource declaration that isn't a list of identifiers.

I thought this had to do with the need to represent a non-present resource definitions or something similar so I threw a few unit test cases at it.

```
try { // No resource declaration here
  // ...
} catch (SomeException ex) {
  // ...
}
```

but in this case the method isn't called at all, which I guess is handled by `BaseTreeVisitor`.

I've been trying to come up with examples that would make the cast impossible but everything I've come up with either doesn't compile or never follows this execution path.

Am I missing a way to write a `try` statement that makes the more generic `Tree` the better choice? Or does this choice stem from the way the interfaces in the library have been structured? It doesn't seem to be enforced by any of the super-interfaces (`TryStatementTree` -> `StatementTree` -> `Tree`). `resourceList` is defined by `TryStatementTree` itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, I stumbled upon the answer in the [SonarQube documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/languages/java/) minutes after posting the question.

It turns out there's a method that works exactly as I expected it to, `TryStatementTree#resource`, which was **deprecated** and then removed in favour of `TryStatementTree#resourceList`, which is exactly what my code uses.

> Deprecated method `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.TryStatementTree.resources()` has been removed, in favor of `org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.TryStatementTree.resourceList()`, as Java 9 allows other trees than `VariableTree` to be placed as resources in `try-with-resources` statements.

Here's an example:

```
SomeAutoCloseableClass myResource = obtainOneSomehow();
try (myResurce) { // No resource declaration here, just an identifier
  // ...
} catch (SomeException ex) {
  // ...
}
```

My project is compiled with the source level set to Java 8 compatibility, which should be amended and a new unit test case should be added to make sure the newly possible way to write a `try-with-resources` block is handled.